# how do i make the black pixels in a PImage transparent?

Tags: processing

The following code makes a rising smoke effect.

```
PImage buffer1;
PImage buffer2;
PImage cooling;
PImage buffer3;
float yInitial = 0.0;
void setup() {
  size(600, 200);
  buffer1 = createImage(width, 200, RGB);
  buffer2 = createImage(width, 200, RGB);
  buffer3 = createImage(width, 200, RGB);
  cooling = createImage(width, 200, RGB);
}
void newLine(int rows) {
  //create row of white pixels
  buffer1.loadPixels();
  for (int x = 0; x<  buffer1.width; x++){
    for(int j = 0; j< rows; j++){
      //find location to draw pixels
      int y = buffer1.height - (j+1); 
      int index = x + y * buffer1.width;
      buffer1.pixels[index] = color(255);
    }
  }
  buffer1.updatePixels();
}
void cool(){
  cooling.loadPixels();
  //start x at 0
  float xoff = 0.0;
  float increment = 0.02;
  for (int x = 0; x < cooling.width; x++){
    xoff += increment;
    //start y at 0
    float yoff = yInitial;
    for (int y = 0; y < cooling.height; y++){
      yoff += increment;
      //calculate noise and enlarge
      float n = noise(xoff, yoff);
      if(n<0.4)
        n = 0;
      float bright = noise(xoff, yoff) *25;
      //set pixel to grayscale value
      cooling.pixels[x+y*cooling.width]= color(bright);
    }
  }
  cooling.updatePixels();
  yInitial += increment;
}

void draw(){
  cool();
  newLine(10);
  background(0);
  buffer1.loadPixels();
  buffer2.loadPixels();
  //look through all x and y coordinates and find the neightboring pixels colour
  for (int x = 1; x < buffer1.width-1; x++) {
    for (int y = 1; y < buffer1.height-1; y++) {
      int index0 = x + y * buffer1.width;
      int index1 = (x+1) + y * buffer1.width;
      int index2 = (x-1) + y * buffer1.width;
      int index3 = x + (y+1) * buffer1.width;
      int index4 = x + (y-1) * buffer1.width;
      color c1 = buffer1.pixels[index1];
      color c2 = buffer1.pixels[index2];
      color c3 = buffer1.pixels[index3];
      color c4 = buffer1.pixels[index4];
      color c5 = cooling.pixels[index0];
      float newC = brightness(c1) + brightness(c2)+ brightness(c3) + brightness(c4);
      newC = newC - brightness(c5);
      newC = newC / 4;
      buffer2.pixels[index4] = color(newC);
    }
  }
  buffer2.updatePixels();

  //swap
  PImage temp = buffer1;
  buffer1 = buffer2;
  buffer2 = temp;
  image(buffer2, 0, 0);
}
```

I intend to use this code to draw the moving smoke over an image that will be in the background (i haven't put this in yet). To do so I attempted to make all the black pixels in the PImage transparent. This should mean only the smoke will be drawn over the background image. I then changed all the transparent pixels back to black after the PImage had been drawn. However, when I added this in the smoke completely stopped being drawn. What have I done wrong and is this the correct way to try to draw the smoke over a background image? Here is my code:

```
PImage buffer1;
PImage buffer2;
PImage cooling;
PImage buffer3;
float yInitial = 0.0;
void setup() {
  size(600, 200);
  buffer1 = createImage(width, 200, RGB);
  buffer2 = createImage(width, 200, RGB);
  buffer3 = createImage(width, 200, RGB);
  cooling = createImage(width, 200, RGB);
}
void newLine(int rows) {
  //create row of white pixels
  buffer1.loadPixels();
  for (int x = 0; x<  buffer1.width; x++){
    for(int j = 0; j< rows; j++){
      //find location to draw pixels
      int y = buffer1.height - (j+1); 
      int index = x + y * buffer1.width;
      buffer1.pixels[index] = color(255);
    }
  }
  buffer1.updatePixels();
}
void cool(){
  cooling.loadPixels();
  //start x at 0
  float xoff = 0.0;
  float increment = 0.02;
  for (int x = 0; x < cooling.width; x++){
    xoff += increment;
    //start y at 0
    float yoff = yInitial;
    for (int y = 0; y < cooling.height; y++){
      yoff += increment;
      //calculate noise and enlarge
      float n = noise(xoff, yoff);
      if(n<0.4)
        n = 0;
      float bright = noise(xoff, yoff) *25;
      //set pixel to grayscale value
      cooling.pixels[x+y*cooling.width]= color(bright);
    }
  }
  cooling.updatePixels();
  yInitial += increment;
}

void draw(){
  cool();
  newLine(10);
  buffer1.loadPixels();
  buffer2.loadPixels();
  //look through all x and y coordinates and find the neightboring pixels colour
  for (int x = 1; x < buffer1.width-1; x++) {
    for (int y = 1; y < buffer1.height-1; y++) {
      int index0 = x + y * buffer1.width;
      int index1 = (x+1) + y * buffer1.width;
      int index2 = (x-1) + y * buffer1.width;
      int index3 = x + (y+1) * buffer1.width;
      int index4 = x + (y-1) * buffer1.width;
      color c1 = buffer1.pixels[index1];
      color c2 = buffer1.pixels[index2];
      color c3 = buffer1.pixels[index3];
      color c4 = buffer1.pixels[index4];
      color c5 = cooling.pixels[index0];
      float newC = brightness(c1) + brightness(c2)+ brightness(c3) + brightness(c4);
      newC = newC - brightness(c5);
      newC = newC / 4;
      buffer2.pixels[index4] = color(newC);
      //make the black pixels transparent
      if(color(buffer2.pixels[index0])==color(0));
        buffer2.pixels[index0] = color(0,0);
      if(color(buffer1.pixels[index0])==color(0));
        buffer1.pixels[index0] = color(0,0);
    }
  }
  buffer2.updatePixels();

  //swap
  PImage temp = buffer1;
  buffer1 = buffer2;
  buffer2 = temp;
  image(buffer2, 0, 0);
  //set transparent pixels back to black
  for (int x = 1; x < buffer1.width-1; x++) {
    for (int y = 1; y < buffer1.height-1; y++) {
      int index0 = x + y * buffer1.width;
      if(color(buffer2.pixels[index0])==color(0,0))
        buffer2.pixels[index0] = color(0);
      if(color(buffer1.pixels[index0])==color(0,0));
        buffer1.pixels[index0] = color(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a pretty cool smoke effect.

There's an easier to composite the smoke effect using [`blendMode()`](https://processing.org/reference/blendMode_.html).
What you're after is something like `blendMode(SCREEN);` or `blendMode(ADD);` which would make black pixels on the effect image transparent.

[image: composited smoke effect over red circle]

```
PImage buffer1;
PImage buffer2;
PImage cooling;
PImage buffer3;
float yInitial = 0.0;

void setup() {
  size(600, 200);
  fill(192,0,0);
  // change blend mode to treat black pixels as transparent
  blendMode(SCREEN);

  buffer1 = createImage(width, 200, RGB);
  buffer2 = createImage(width, 200, RGB);
  buffer3 = createImage(width, 200, RGB);
  cooling = createImage(width, 200, RGB);
}
void newLine(int rows) {
  //create row of white pixels
  buffer1.loadPixels();
  for (int x = 0; x<  buffer1.width; x++){
    for(int j = 0; j< rows; j++){
      //find location to draw pixels
      int y = buffer1.height - (j+1); 
      int index = x + y * buffer1.width;
      buffer1.pixels[index] = color(255);
    }
  }
  buffer1.updatePixels();
}
void cool(){
  cooling.loadPixels();
  //start x at 0
  float xoff = 0.0;
  float increment = 0.02;
  for (int x = 0; x < cooling.width; x++){
    xoff += increment;
    //start y at 0
    float yoff = yInitial;
    for (int y = 0; y < cooling.height; y++){
      yoff += increment;
      //calculate noise and enlarge
      float n = noise(xoff, yoff);
      if(n<0.4)
        n = 0;
      float bright = noise(xoff, yoff) *25;
      //set pixel to grayscale value
      cooling.pixels[x+y*cooling.width]= color(bright);
    }
  }
  cooling.updatePixels();
  yInitial += increment;
}

void updateSmokeEffect(){
  cool();
  newLine(10);
  buffer1.loadPixels();
  buffer2.loadPixels();
  //look through all x and y coordinates and find the neightboring pixels colour
  for (int x = 1; x < buffer1.width-1; x++) {
    for (int y = 1; y < buffer1.height-1; y++) {
      int index0 = x + y * buffer1.width;
      int index1 = (x+1) + y * buffer1.width;
      int index2 = (x-1) + y * buffer1.width;
      int index3 = x + (y+1) * buffer1.width;
      int index4 = x + (y-1) * buffer1.width;
      color c1 = buffer1.pixels[index1];
      color c2 = buffer1.pixels[index2];
      color c3 = buffer1.pixels[index3];
      color c4 = buffer1.pixels[index4];
      color c5 = cooling.pixels[index0];
      float newC = brightness(c1) + brightness(c2)+ brightness(c3) + brightness(c4);
      newC = newC - brightness(c5);
      newC = newC / 4;
      buffer2.pixels[index4] = color(newC);
    }
  }
  buffer2.updatePixels();

  swapBuffers();
}

void swapBuffers(){
  //swap
  PImage temp = buffer1;
  buffer1 = buffer2;
  buffer2 = temp;
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  // test drawing something in the background
  ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,30,30);

  updateSmokeEffect();
  // render blended image on top
  image(buffer2, 0, 0);
}
```

You can use `blendMode(BLEND)` to revert back to the default blend mode:

```
void draw(){
  background(0);
  blendMode(ADD);
  // test drawing something in the background
  ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,30,30);

  updateSmokeEffect();
  // render blended image on top
  image(buffer2, 0, 0);

  blendMode(BLEND);
  // test drawing something in the foreground
  ellipse(mouseX + 35,mouseY,30,30);
}
```

[image: mixing blend modes to render a circle in the background behind the smoke effect and one in the foreground in front of the smoke effect]

Additionally you can checkout [`PGraphics`](https://processing.org/reference/PGraphics.html) to mimic layers, though for pixel effects like that you can do plenty with `PImage` (and it's `set()` / `copy()` / `blend()` / etc. methods)

You might also be interested [shaders](https://processing.org/tutorials/pshader/): fragment shaders in particular for "pixel" manipulation on the GPU